# Changing the orientation of a SplitView

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, splitview

I'm making a UWP (Windows 10) app. I'd like to know, is it possible to change the orientation of a `SplitView`? Typically, it's ordered like this:

```
______________________________________________
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|    Pane     |          Content             |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
|             |                              |
----------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to change the orientation to:

```
______________________________________________
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                     Pane                   |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
----------------------------------------------
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                    Content                 |
|                                            |
|                                            |
|                                            |
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported by the platform ([SplitVew.PanePlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitviewpaneplacement.aspx) property can only be left or right).

You can likely achieve a somewhat similar affect by placing a command bar at the top of your application.